# Element still thinks it's being hovered after moving from under cursor

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

**"Solution" Edit:** I ended up just changing the layout a bit to get around this issue, as shown below. The original problematic behavior was present in other browsers as well, so I simply kept the button in place instead of sliding it to the left upon opening the search box.

[image: Revised GIF]

**--------- Original Question ---------**

I wasn't sure how to word my title, but let me explain my issue. Using pure CSS and HTML, I'm making an expanding search box. The problem I have is when closing the search box, if you don't move your mouse, the button will still be shown as hovered, even though it has moved. Here is my problem:

[image: GIF of problem]

What can I do to prevent this, if possible? It just messes with the look of the animation even if you move off of it when you click. The animation is smoother than shown. Using latest Chrome on W7.

**CSS:**

```
div#nav-search {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
nav#header-nav.small div#nav-search {
  top: 18px;
}
div#nav-search.open {
  background-color: #FFBC43;
  width: 95%;
}
div#nav-search-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 34px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button#nav-search-btn { 
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  width: 60px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button#nav-search-btn span { 
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url({{ 'search-gold.png' | asset_url }});
  background-size: 24px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
button#nav-search-btn:hover { 
  background-color: #FFBC43;
}
button#nav-search-btn:hover > span, div#nav-search.open > button#nav-search-btn span { 
  background-image: url({{ 'search-brown.png' | asset_url }});
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-right transition">
  <span class="phone-number">{{ settings.company_phone }}</span>
  <div id="nav-search">
    <button id="nav-search-btn"><span></span></button>
    <div id="nav-search-wrapper">Wrapper filler text</div>
  </div>
  <a href="/cart" id="nav-cart-btn"></a>        
</div>
```

Comment: (at least) to me, creating your code into a snippet failed to generate your sample image. Could you possibly check that you've included all the relevant parts?

Comment: @jbutler483 I actually forgot that it's pure CSS/HTML except I used JS to add a class on click. However, I ended up just moving the search button to the right side and tweaked the animation. Similar result, but without this issue. Plus I guess it's nice if you clicked it on accident, you don't have to "chase" the close button. Just click again. I may even update it so its a close button if the field is empty, but switches to a submit button if you type something.